# Intersection Observer: how to use addClassList on all elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, viewport, intersection-observer

I am trying to trigger the CSS animations of my page in the user's viewport only. Meaning the animation will start only once the element is visible. For that I decided to use the Intersection Observer but it only add my class to the first element with that class name, instead of all of them.

JS:
.animate__animated has the 'animation-play-state: paused' property by default, and if the class is visible, it adds the 'is-running' class containing 'animation-play-state:running'. It works great with the first element, but not for the second (and others in my page).

How can I pass all the instances of that class into the entries? Can I even do that with the Intersection Observer? I am new to JS, I mostly follow tutorials online  and can't seem to find a workaround.

```
 const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    // Loop over the entries
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      // If the element is visible
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        // Set to animation-play-state: running
        entry.target.classList.add('is-running');
      }
    });
  });
  
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('.animate__animated'));
```

CSS:

```
    .animate__animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: var(--animate-duration);
    animation-duration: var(--animate-duration);
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.is-running {
    animation-play-state: running;
 }
```

Html:

```
 <nav class="navbar has-text-white has-shadow" style="background:#231f20; max-height:80px;">

    <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a href="index.html" class="narvbar-item pl-2">
            <img src="img/logo-txt.png" alt="Cheff Burgers Logo" class="pt-4 pl-5 animate__animated animate__lightSpeedInLeft" >
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-burger has-text-white" id="burger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-menu pb-5" id="nav-links" style="background-color:#231f20;">

        <div class="navbar-end pr-6 mr-6 mt-5 animate__animated anim1 animate__lightSpeedInRight">
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-item has-text-white">Accueil</a>
            <a href="menu.html" class="navbar-item has-text-white">Menu</a>
            <a href="evenements.html" class="navbar-item has-text-white">Evènements</a>
            <a href="contact.html" class="navbar-item has-text-white">Horaires & Contact</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector()` returns a single result. `.querySelectorAll()` will return them all. But you'll have to iterate over them to add observers.

Comment: Thanks! missd that one. I got it to work now :D